# How to use thickbox image gallery in Codeigniter?

Tags: jquery, thickbox

I have integrate jQuery thick box in Codeigniter, when I am using this thick box for the singe image then it will work, but when I am using the same thickbox for image gallery by applying the "rel" attributes to anchor tag then it won't work it shows only loading bar.

Comment: Nothing to do with codeigniter. Tag should be js or jquery etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Dear please remove the @ reference from thickbox.js file in rel attributes

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code, i have also use route functionality,

```
<div class="inner_page_content">  
<?php for($i=0;$i<count($imagesArr);$i++) { ?>  
<a href="<?php echo site_url();?>uploads/<?php echo $imagesArr[$i]['fileName'];?>" class="thickbox myimggallery" rel="gallery-plants">
<img src="<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/thumb1_<?php echo $imagesArr[$i]['fileName'];?>"/>
</a>  
<?php }?> 
 </div>
```